# Problem with Solve for simple equation

Tags: equation-solving

I have a simple question, but just can't figure it out.

I have the following model equation to get a peak. I want to get the the two t-values on the left and right side of the peak, where the model has a height (y-value) of 1*10^-6.

```
model=(1.87429 E^(-((0.982704 (30.8 - 3.35121 t)^2)/t)))/Sqrt[t]
```

I tried:

```
Solve[model == 10^-6, t]
```

but the result is `{}`.

and I get the message

> Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.

I then tried `Reduce`, but that also doesn't work.

The problem seems really easy, but I think I have a fundamental misunderstanding here.

Comment: If you are really interested in finding the maximum (peak) of `model`, why don't you just go for it directly? `FindMaximum[model, {t, 10}]` returns `{0.618628, {t -> 9.16809}}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
model = (1.87429 E^(-((0.982704 (30.8 - 3.35121 t)^2)/t)))/Sqrt[t];

LogPlot[{model, 10^-6}, {t, 6, 14}]
```

[image]

Use `NSolve` and restrict the domain to `Reals`

```
NSolve[model == 10^-6, t, Reals]

(*  {{t -> 6.39267}, {t -> 13.1499}}  *)
```

Or use `Reduce` restricted to `Reals`

```
Off[Reduce::ratnz]

Reduce[model == 10^-6, t, Reals]

(*  t == 6.39267 || t == 13.1499  *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Solve tries to find a closed form solution - and is not successful in this case. You can get a solution to your problem by using a numerical method, e.g. FindRoot. 
First

```
f[t_] := (1.87429 E^(-((0.982704 (30.8 - 3.35121 t)^2)/t)))/Sqrt[t]
```

then (I did a Plot to have an estimate of the solution)

```
sol = FindRoot[f[t] - 10^(-6), {t, 6.}]
```

(* {t -> 6.39267} *)

result:

```
f[t /. sol]
```

(* 10.^(-6) *)

Comment: +1 for telling me, why Solve didn't work in that context. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes plotting and/or reformulating the equation for a variety of ranges the variable of interest along with FindRoot works:

```
model = (1.87429 E^(-((0.982704 (30.8 - 3.35121 t)^2)/t)))/Sqrt[t]
Plot[Log10[model], {t, 6, 7}]
FindRoot[Log10[model] == -6, {t, 6}]

(* {t -> 6.39267} *)
```

[image: Function values near solution]